# Conditionally execute useContext in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, preact, use-context, createcontext

I am looking to conditionally call useContext. This is my original code, which runs correctly, but fails tslint.

Component that calls ***useResourceScope*** - say ***Component1***

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export function useSubscribeListItemStore(
  inputResources?: ResourceScope
) {
  const resources = inputResources || useResourceScope();
  const listItemStore = resources.consume(listItemStoreKey);
  
  useEffect(function subscribeListItemStore() {
    // do some logic
  }, []);
}
```

Component that defines ***useResourceScope*** - say ***Component2***

```
import { createContext } from 'preact';
import { useContext } from 'preact/hooks';

export const ResourceScopeContext = createContext<ResourceScope | undefined>(undefined);

export function useResourceScope(): ResourceScope {
  const resources = useContext(ResourceScopeContext);
  if (!resources) {
    throw new Error(
      'error message'
    );
  }
  return resources;
}
```

This gives me a tslint error: **(react-hooks-nesting) A hook cannot be used in a conditional expression**

This is my attempt at solving this, but does not work. It does not run correctly and fails at the *useContext* line in *Component2* My thought was that since *useContext* **must** be called to fix the tslint errors, I decided to conditionally call the useContext with different created contexts. If the variable `inputResources` is passed in, it calls `useContext` with a placeholder context called `PlaceHolderContext`, which it ignores and returns `inputResources`. If not, it does `useContext` using the intended `ResourceScopeContext` value.

Component that calls ***useResourceScope*** - say ***Component1***

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export function useSubscribeListItemStore(
  inputResources?: ResourceScope
) {
  const resources = useResourceScope(inputResources);
  const listItemStore = resources.consume(listItemStoreKey);
  
  useEffect(function subscribeListItemStore() {
    // do some logic
  }, []);
}
```

Component that defines ***useResourceScope*** - say ***Component2***

```
import { createContext } from 'preact';
import { useContext } from 'preact/hooks';

export const ResourceScopeContext = createContext<ResourceScope | undefined>(undefined);

export function useResourceScope(inputResources?: ResourceScope): ResourceScope {
  const PlaceHolderContext = createContext({ foo: 'bar' });
  const createdContext = inputResources ? PlaceHolderContext : ResourceScopeContext;

  const resources = useContext(createdContext as any);

  if (inputResources) {
    return inputResources;
  }

  if (!resources) {
    throw new Error(
      'error message'
    );
  }
  return resources as any;
}
```

Could you suggest how I can resolve tslint error here without breaking it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than conditionally calling the hook, can you conditionally use its return value?

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export function useSubscribeListItemStore(
  inputResources?: ResourceScope
) {
  const contextResources = useResourceScope();
  const resources = inputResources || contextResources;

  const listItemStore = resources.consume(listItemStoreKey);
  
  useEffect(function subscribeListItemStore() {
    // do some logic
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the idea. I tried doing that, but it gives me the same runtime error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'context' of undefined when I click a button. The error originates from the line const resources = useContext(ResourceScopeContext);

Comment: Do you have the context provider higher up the component tree?

Comment: you are right, I don't. But without changing the context provider to be available up the component tree, is there a change I can make in const resources = useContext(ResourceScopeContext); so as to not result in an error? I am not going to be using the resources returned here. I can pass in the inputResources like in my original attempt and make it return that, I only want it to not result in an error.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure what you're asking. the `useContext` hook only works in components lower in a React component tree from its provider.

Comment: right! My apologies for not being clear. I was asking - can I do const notGoingToBeUsingThisResource = useContext(something that does not result in an error); Please let me know if this does not make sense, and I can go back and study useContext.

Comment: No, I believe you'll always get an error if you use the `useContext` hook without a provider

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233210/discussion-between-learntoimprove-and-nick).

Answer (score 1):

First off, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html read the bold text:

> Only Call Hooks at the Top Level

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.

That being said, https://aganglada.com/blog/how-to-break-the-rules-with-conditional-hooks

Comment: linked site has disappeared.